# Copy a row column from one table to another in ON CONFLICT

Tags: sql, postgresql, unique, upsert

Using Postgres 9.6, I am copying a row(selected columns) from one table to another. I am running:

```
INSERT INTO copy_on_write(id, images)
    SELECT id, images
    FROM listings
    WHERE id = 1 AND posted_by = foo
ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET images = listings.images
```

With the conflict because id already exists, I am getting `missing FROM-clause entry for table "listings"`.

So, I tried:

```
INSERT INTO copy_on_write(id, images)
    SELECT id, images
    FROM listings
    WHERE id = 1 AND posted_by = foo
ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET images = images FROM listings
```

but then I get `syntax error at or near "FROM"`

How do I handle this `ON CONFLICT (id)` so it updates the images column if the row id already exists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `excluded`:

```
INSERT INTO copy_on_write(id, images) 
SELECT id, images 
FROM listings 
WHERE id = 1 AND posted_by = 'foo' 
ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET images = excluded.images;
```

From [the documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html)

> conflict_action
>
> (...) The SET and WHERE clauses in ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE have access to the existing row using the table's name (or an alias), and to rows proposed for insertion using the special `excluded` table.